# facebook feed dialog redirects

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

i have set up an facebook app. and i have used the Direct Url that i have found in the Feed Dialog Page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

my problem is it redirects to the same url even if the visitors clicks "Cancel" !?? i just want to redirect them to the download page when they click "Share" and if they clicked "Cancel" redirect them to same page they landed on

please any help would be appreciated as i am not a coder!

and please how can i gather users email address? is it possible through feed dialog?

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is it redirects to the same url even if the visitors clicks "Cancel"

It **only** redirects to `redirect_uri` if the user cancels. If he goes through with sharing, then the dialog is *supposed* to redirect to the new post created on Facebook.

> please any help would be appreciated

Don’t call the dialog by URL, but use the JavaScript SDK to call it (FB.ui).

> as i am not a coder!

Then learn some basics … or get paid support.

> and please how can i gather users email address? is it possible through feed dialog?

No, of course not – the *feed* dialog is for posting something on a user’s *feed*.

To get user information, you have to log the user in into your app, aks for the necessary permissions, and then query the Graph API for the info you want. Please start by reading the relevant chapters in Facebook’s documentation.

Comment: thanks for replay..but what if i want to redirect users to any external page when they click "share" ? i am doing all this as a content locker (they click on the share button >the dialog pop up >they click share>they redirected to a page that i specify> ?? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that’s possible, and I already suggested at how to do it.